# How to build ajax-chartjs line-chart in asp mvc application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I have following code in my view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/newcss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/chartscripts")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.bundle.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/GraphicsController/AjaxChart",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("Linecanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1,
        {   type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ContentIds))],
                datasets: [{
                        label: "Common Responses",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        data: [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ContentIds))]
                    },{
                        label: "Delayed Responses",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        data: 
[@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.DelayedResponseTimes))]
                    }]},
            options:{title:
                    {display: true,
                        text: "Graphic"},
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: true
                }});},
    error: function OnErrorCall_(repo) {alert("Woops something went wrong, 
pls try later !");}});
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div-chart">
        <canvas id="Linecanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    ...
<body>
```

And in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AjaxChart() {
  IEnumerable < DBContent > contents = db.DBContents;

  var delayedResponses = contents.Where(r => r.DelayedResponseTime != 0).Select(x => x.DelayedResponseTime);
  var commonResponses = contents.Where(r => r.CommonResponseTime != 0).Select(x => x.CommonResponseTime);
  ViewBag.DelayedResponseTimes = delayedResponses.ToList();
  ViewBag.CommonResponseTimes = commonResponses.ToList();

  var ContentIds = new List < int > () {};
  for (var i = 1; i <= delayedResponses.Count(); i++) {
    ContentIds.Add(i);
  }
  ViewBag.ContentIds = ContentIds;
  return Json(delayedResponses.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I tried to build line chart with chartjs, and without Ajax I have done it, but I want to my chart rebuild automatically without page refreshing and without any actions on page (triggers for Ajax like clicking buttons etc) when I get a new items in the database. With this code I always go to the `error` block.

Comment: I think you need to use [HttpGet] instead of [HttpPost]

Comment: @NishanChathuranga i tried to change type of ajax and AjaxChart's annotation to Get, but nothing has changed.

Comment: It should be a get method since you are requesting data. Try changing public ActionResult to public JsonResult

Comment: I think there is a typo in the `label: "Common Responses",`, you used `ContentIds`, but it seems you wanted `CommonResponseTimes`. I corrected that in my answer.

Comment: If you change the controller to `[HttpGet]`, then you should change Ajax to `type: "get"` too.

Comment: @NishanChathuranga i tried to change my code in according to your and Racil's advices and now i have following code - controller: [link](https://pastebin.com/CeKCHx1G) view: [link](https://pastebin.com/MJWgGWaN) , but I'm still get the error message. In debug mode i see that interpreter don't come to AjaxChart() method. The same situation in case i change AjaxChart's annotation and type of ajax to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `ViewBag` with Ajax, you can only return one single result object. Combine all those returned objects as properties of one parent object:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxChart() {
    IEnumerable<DBContent> contents = db.DBContents;

    var delayedResponses = contents.Where(r => r.DelayedResponseTime != 0)
                                   .Select(x => x.DelayedResponseTime);
    var commonResponses = contents.Where(r => r.CommonResponseTime != 0)
                                  .Select(x => x.CommonResponseTime);

    var ContentIds = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 1; i <= delayedResponses.Count(); i++) {
        ContentIds.Add(i);
    }

    var result = new {
        DelayedResponseTimes = delayedResponses.ToList(),
        CommonResponseTimes = commonResponses.ToList(),
        ContentIds = ContentIds
    };
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now, in your jQuery, you need to get the data (you're not doing that). Change the line:

```
success: function () {
```

to:

```
success: function (result) {
```

And then you need to change all those line using `ViewBag` to using the `result` parameter:

```
success: function(result) {
  var ctx1 = document.getElementById("Linecanvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: result.ContentIds,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Common Responses",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: result.CommonResponseTimes
      }, {
        label: "Delayed Responses",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: result.DelayedResponseTimes
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Graphic"
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true
    }
  });
},
```

And finally, in the URL to your method, you must use the name of the controller without the suffix, so change this line:

```
url: "/GraphicsController/AjaxChart",
```

to:

```
url: "/Graphics/AjaxChart",
```

It is better to let ASP generate the URL for you, in case you change your routing or rename your method:

```
url: @Url.Action(nameof(GraphicsController.AjaxChart), "Graphics"),
```

Comment: @SOreadytohelp  Thanks for broad answer. I combined your and others answers, and got this code: 
controller: [link](https://pastebin.com/CeKCHx1G)
view: [link](https://pastebin.com/MJWgGWaN)

, but I'm still get the error message. In debug mode i see that interpreter don't come to AjaxChart() method.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that the URL was wrong. See the last part of my updated answer. You must use `Graphics` instead of `GraphicsController` when you create the URL. Also I noticed in your code that you're still using `HttpPost`. Since you're not sending any parameters to `AjaxChart`, then it is better to use `HttpGet` and change Ajax to `type: "get"`. If you want to continue using `HttpPost`, then change the last line in your controller `return Json(result);`. There is not point in allowing `GET` with `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if you're not using it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks ... it Successfully works for me. But there is little change needed:

`public ActionResult AjaxChart()`

to:

`public JsonResult AjaxChart()`